# how to use Python's loop to develop KNN alogarithm from scratch

Tags: python, knn

I am learning Python and practicing to develop KNN  without using libraries

Here are the 3 major steps I wanted to take, but my code is cluttered with errors.

The data I am playing with has 4 features and two classes.

Please see what I am trying to do below and help improve it- the main error I am getting is:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Planning to approach it in 3 stage:

1. To prepare the data, splitting (for evaluation):

   ```
   random.shuffle(iris)
   #this is not working for me i dont know why?????

   X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)` 
   print (len (X_train)) # to recheck the sucess of the split
   ```
2. to measure all distances from KNN

   ```
   from math import sqrt
   from collections import Counter
   #new_measure=(X_new)
   #X_new= [1,2,3,4]
   distance=[]
   for group in X_train:
       for features in X_train:
          Eu_dis= sqrt( (X_new [0]- X_train[0])**2 + (X_new [1]- X_train[1])**2+(X_new [2]- X_train[2])**2+(X_new [3]- X_train[3])**2)
   ```
3. to identify the nearest KNNs and identify the most likely class

How do I proceed after this?

Answer (score 1):

here are all need functions:
1. calculate the Euclidean distance between two vectors
2. locate the most similar neighbors
3. make a classification prediction with neighbors

```
# calculate the Euclidean distance between two vectors
def euclidean_distance(row1, row2):
    distance = 0.0
    for i in range(len(row1)-1):
        distance += (row1[i] - row2[i])**2
    return sqrt(distance)

# Locate the most similar neighbors
def get_neighbors(train, test_row, num_neighbors):
    distances = list()
    for train_row in train:
        dist = euclidean_distance(test_row, train_row)
        distances.append((train_row, dist))
    distances.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1])
    neighbors = list()
    for i in range(num_neighbors):
        neighbors.append(distances[i][0])
    return neighbors

# Make a classification prediction with neighbors
def predict_classification(train, test_row, num_neighbors):
    neighbors = get_neighbors(train, test_row, num_neighbors)
    output_values = [row[-1] for row in neighbors]
    prediction = max(set(output_values), key=output_values.count)
    return prediction
```

Comment: thanks, very helpful. I used your tips and tried to apply it on Iris data. I have one more error which you may have a solution from . This is the error  , what do you think is happening .10     distance = 0.0
     11     for i in range(len(row1)-1):
---> 12         distance += (row1[i] - row2[i])**2
     13     return sqrt(distance)
     14 

IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4